# UICollectionView allowsMultipleSelelections not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to make some photoPicker with CollectionView.

Have

```
allowsMultipleSelection = YES
```

Using following method

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    selectedPictures = [NSMutableArray array];

    [selectedPictures addObject:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    NSLog(@"Selected list:\n %@", selectedPictures);

    NSLog(@"Objects in Array %i", selectedPictures.count);

}
```

While I am selecting cells, it's always adding to MutableArray only one object according it's indexPath. What could be an issue?

Comment: objectAtIndex:indexPath.item here objectAtIndex:indexPath.row is correct or objectAtIndex:indexPath.item  which one is corret

Comment: need reference http://www.appcoda.com/ios-collection-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't u keep the `selectedPictures` as a member variable

in your code

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

selectedPictures = [NSMutableArray array]; //keep on creation the new array on each selection

[selectedPictures addObject:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]; //adding the selected images means single image 

NSLog(@"Selected list:\n %@", selectedPictures);

NSLog(@"Objects in Array %i", selectedPictures.count);

}
```

try this

put his in `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    selectedPictures =  [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //initilise hear
  }



 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   //  selectedPictures = [NSMutableArray array]; //keep on creation the new array on each selection

[selectedPictures addObject:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]; //adding the   selected images means single image to already initialised array 

 NSLog(@"Selected list:\n %@", selectedPictures);

 NSLog(@"Objects in Array %i", selectedPictures.count);

}
```

Hope this helps u .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check also this

Your observation is correct. This behavior is happening due to the reuse of cells. But you dont have to do any thing with the prepareForReuse. Instead do your check in cellForItem and set the properties accordingly. Some thing like..

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


if (cell.selected) {
     cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // highlight selection 
}
else
{
     cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Default color
}
return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

    UICollectionViewCell *datasetCell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // highlight selection
 }  

 -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UICollectionViewCell *datasetCell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Default color
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it may be caused by not calling super. While the documentation for UICollectionReusableView fails to mention this, the documentation for UITableViewCell, which has the same method, does.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse]
    // Your code here.
}
```

***Old Answer:***

This may be a bug with the UICollectionView.

What's happening is cells that were previously selected are being reused and maintain the selected state. The collection view isn't setting selected to "NO".

The solution is to reset the the selected state in prepareForReuse of the cell:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    self.selected = NO;
}
```

If the reused cell is selected, the collection view will set selected to "YES" after prepareForReuse is called.

This is something the UICollectionView should be doing on it's own. Thankfully the solution is simple. Unfortunately I spent a ton of time working around this bug by tracking my own select state. I didn't realize why it was happening until I was working on another project with smaller cells.

Comment: but what doest it mean variable selected?

Comment: it is bool variable instead use this

Answer (score -1):

Also Try this
I'm not seeing why this would take place. I do not believe the issue is the use of row vs item, though you really should use item. I can imagine, though, if your collection view has more than one section, that only looking at row/item but ignoring section would be a problem (i.e. it would select the same item number in every section).

To cut the Gordian knot, I'd suggest saving the NSIndexPath of the selected item, and then using that for the basis of comparison. That also makes it easy to render an optimization in didSelectItemAtIndexPath. Anyway, first define your property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *selectedItemIndexPath;
```

And then implement cellForItemAtIndexPath and didSelectItemAtIndexPath:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.imageView.image = ...

    if (self.selectedItemIndexPath != nil && [indexPath compare:self.selectedItemIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
        cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0;
    } else {
        cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = nil;
        cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // always reload the selected cell, so we will add the border to that cell

    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];

    if (self.selectedItemIndexPath)
    {
        // if we had a previously selected cell

        if ([indexPath compare:self.selectedItemIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            // if it's the same as the one we just tapped on, then we're unselecting it

            self.selectedItemIndexPath = nil;
        }
        else
        {
            // if it's different, then add that old one to our list of cells to reload, and
            // save the currently selected indexPath

            [indexPaths addObject:self.selectedItemIndexPath];
            self.selectedItemIndexPath = indexPath;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // else, we didn't have previously selected cell, so we only need to save this indexPath for future reference

        self.selectedItemIndexPath = indexPath;
    }

    // and now only reload only the cells that need updating

    [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved my issue;

The problem was very simple, I should have initialise MutableArray not in the Method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, but in the `ViewDidLoad`. Now it adding pictures one by one

Comment: that is what i mentioned in my answer ... :)

Comment: @Shan sorry didn't see that :) were too many answers :) Thank you